# Controlling flow through an output pipe

Tags: pressure, airflow, valves

I wish to limit my flow through the output to a certain exact value. In this case to 10 lpm, what method or valve can I use to this task?

At the moment the flow keeps on fluctuating between 10.1-11.2 (seen on digital flow meter)

Any method with which the extra gas may pass out or the control over the flow is achieved more efficiently!

PS: It is located at the output of an oxygen concentrator

pic: [image]

Schematic: [image: The schematic showing the placement of rotameter after the surge tank which stores oxygen. I wish to observe low fluctuations in the output oxygen flow rate, like in the range of 10+-0.2 lpm]

Comment: If the gas is passing out through a constant restriction / resistance then you only need a pressure regulator. If you are trying to maintain a flow rate against a variable restriction things get more complicated. Please [edit] your question to give more details and, perhaps, a schematic indicating the source, the pressures, whether or not a pump is involved, whether or not it has variable speed control and details on the restrictions. "Exact" isn't an engineering specification. Use numbers to specify a tolerance.

Comment: Can you switch from using a rotameter to a flow control valve with feedback control?

Comment: a mass flow controller if you want to go fancy. If you just want a steady value but intend to still manually dial it in, an electronic proportional valve (with current control) is inexpensive. For the p-valve current control, results will be even better if you superimpose a slight dither waveform (~10% of full scale current amplitude, 200Hz typical for this). Adding some extra pressure drop can sometimes also be helpful to stabilize the flow

Comment: I have updated the schematic in the post. I need the solution to be low-cost and easy to implement at the moment, and in the future, we may apply solutions with a control strategy.

Comment: Is there any valve available that can let the extra air go out from there and just pass in the air in the range of 10 LPM. because, in this way, it will not create back-pressure in the system, right?

Comment: Use a pressure control valve.  Or use pressure relief valves to maintain a max pressure.  If the pressure is constant, flow should be constant.  By the way, you need relief valves in this system.

Comment: What's the difference between a pressure control valve and a pressure relief valve? Will both expel the extra gas to the ambient?

Comment: Can someone guide me to what all will I need to construct a flow control valve with feedback control? I have studied control theory but only the basic course and never implemented it in real life. Can someone suggest me all the parts, and I will take up from there. Thanks a lot!